# deshabilitar un enlace

Tags: javascript

Quiero deshabilitar este enlace durante unos segundos.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-rel="popup" id="deshabilitar" type="button" data-icon="cloud-upload" data-iconshadow="true" onclick="deshabilitar()"></a>
```

para que solo permita clicar una vez. En la funcion tengo este codigo pero no me lo hace y no veo el porque. Gracias.

```
 var button = $('#deshabilitar');
button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
setTimeout(function() {
     button.removeAttr('disabled');
},3000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u2c6wdgq/1/

Comment: Pon un jsfiddle para que podamos verlo mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es asignarle a el enlace la propiedad `pointer-events` de  `css` con valor `none` mediante `javascript` y en unos segundos después remover ese propiedad para que vuelva a estar habilitado.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

Este sería el `HTML`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="deshabilitar(this)">Dame click</a>
```

Y este el `javascript`:

```
function deshabilitar( link ){
    link.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    link.style.color = '#bbb';

    setTimeout(function(){
        link.style.pointerEvents = null;
        link.style.color = 'blue';
    }, 3000);
}
```

Lo he probado y funciona, espero y te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Quizá no tenías bien la referencia, prueba con:

```
function deshabilitar() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando sea pulsado, durante unos segundos no se pueda volver a pulsar. Preo como esta ahi si puedo hacerlo de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema está en que no se puede añadir el atributo `disabled` a un enlace. En este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777003/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-disable-enable-buttons-and-links-jquery-bootstrap) (en inglés) tienes información de cual es la mejor manera de deshabilitarlo

Comment: Cierto justo lo estaba viendo, recomiendan eliminar en propio enlace para lograrlo.

Comment: Gracias, voy a mirarlo a ver que dice

Answer (score 1):

Un link no es un control de formulario para que puedas deshabilitarlo y evitar el comportamiento por defecto.

Intenta agregando un estado de habilitado/deshabilitado al link y segun el estado del link, haces la accion correspondiente.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```js
$('#deshabilitar').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this)
   
   if($this.hasClass('inhabilitado')) {
     alert("link unhabilitado");
   }
   
    $this.addClass('inhabilitado');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.removeClass('inhabilitado');
        alert("link habilitado")
    }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.inhabilitado{
  color:#ccc;
  cursor:default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-rel="popup" id="deshabilitar" type="button" data-iconshadow="true">link</a>
```

Lo que hace es simple, agregar una clase llamado `deshabilitado` cuando se hace clic sobre elemento. Esta clase cambia el color y el cursor para dar la impresion que esta deshabilitada. Luego despues del tiempo transcurrido se eliminan los estilos y el link vuelve a estar habilitado.

Answer (score 0):

```
function  noEjecutarLink(e) {
    // prevenir comportamento normal del link
    e.preventDefault();
    // código a executar aqui
}

function generarLink(id){   
    let link=document.getElementById('link');//el div donde se agrega el >atributo a
    link.innerHTML = ''//limpia la etiqueta del atributo a
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", `../institucional?id=${id}`);//la pagina >destino
    let aTexto = document.createTextNode("INSTITUCIONAL");//rotulo del >link

    a.appendChild(aTexto);
    link.appendChild(a);

    if (id===0){
    //la primera vez el id es 0; la funcion generarLink se llama luego de >encontrar un
    // id valido
        a.style.cursor='not-allowed';//cursor prohibido
        a.addEventListener('click', noEjecutarLink, false);
    }
}


//se carga por primera vez la pagina
generarLink(0);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué el comentario `// código a executar aqui`? Además, en lo posible, procura explicar el código también fuera de los comentarios, para mejor legibilidad. Recuerda siempre responder en base a [answer].